# failed retrieving file from mirror.erickochen.nl

Tags: archlinux

When I run pacman -Syu to update, it first shows no error, I normally update everything and after that, I run pacman -Syu again, it shows this, what is the reason and any solution?

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
core is up to date
extra is up to date
community is up to date
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.erickochen.nl : Failed to connect to mirror.erickochen.nl port 443 after 5241 ms: Connection timed out
error: failed retrieving file 'extra.db' from mirror.erickochen.nl : Failed to connect to mirror.erickochen.nl port 443 after 5202 ms: Connection timed out
error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from mirror.erickochen.nl : Failed to connect to mirror.erickochen.nl port 443 after 5202 ms: Connection timed out
warning: too many errors from mirror.erickochen.nl, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
:: Starting full system upgrade...
there is nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes mirrors go offline, it's recommended to have multiple mirrors so you don't have a single point of failure, as well as keeping mirrors updated. Using [reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/reflector) is recommended since it also finds fast candidates based on your location.

For the time being, edit `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and uncomment a couple of mirrors, then try updating again.